# how to access only admin can run command on telegram in python

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telethon

Hi I am trying to access only admin can run command on telegram in python

let's say /addtoken command in public group and only can run admin so I implemented some script

but user id and sender id is different and I am admin of the group

```
@BOT.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/addtoken'))
async def addToken(event):
    async for user in BOT.iter_participants(event.chat_id,filter=ChannelParticipantsAdmins):
        print("user",user.id)
        print("sender",event.sender_id)

        if user.id == event.sender_id:
            await event.respond("Please send me the contract address of the token you would like to add to this group. ",parse_mode = 'HTML')
            break
        else:
            await event.respond("You are not an admin of this group.",parse_mode = 'HTML')
            break 
    raise events.StopPropagation
```

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching all participants, and breaking on the first one. There may be multiple admins. If the first one is the wrong one, the loop will exit without checking the rest.

You should use [`client.get_permissions`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.chats.ChatMethods.get_permissions) which is used for checking a single user:

```py
permissions = await BOT.get_permissions(event.sender_id)
if permissions.is_admin:
    print('it is an admin')
else:
    print('it is a normal user')
```